# Having problem with alias?

Tags: alias, ls, prompt

I am trying to define alias for a group of commands counting and displaying the number of all files in account’s space with the names starting with g, t, and w. I got the result with the following command.

```
   find $HOME -name '[gtw]*' | wc -l
```

But when I try to give the command, alias I got error

```
  alias noAgtw='find $HOME -name '[gtw]*'| wc -l '
```

The error reads like this

```
noAgtw

find: paths must precede expression: testing

Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec]  

[path...] [expression] 

0
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
alias noAgtw="find $HOME -name '[gtw]*' | wc -l"
```

or:

```
alias noAgtw='find '"$HOME"' -name "[gtw]*" | wc -l'
```

Looking at this new definition, I think you can figure that you misused simple quotes...

Also, never use a variable (as in your case `$HOME` is) inside single quotes. See why here:

- [What’s the Difference Between Single and Double Quotes in the Bash Shell?](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/29980/whats-the-difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-the-bash-shell/).

Comment: Will you please answer my next question regarding alias?

Comment: I just posted it!!